# SQL Server Where Clause Case Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a Where Clause that checks the existence of rows in a subquery, but I only want to execute that check if a bit is set to 1.  So for example:

```
Select * from Listing l
Where
l.IsDeleted=1 
AND CASE WHEN @MustHasPicture = 1  THEN 
(
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[ListingPictures] AS [lp]
        INNER JOIN Listing l ON lp.ListingID=l.ID
    )
)
ELSE 1 END = 1
```

This syntax is wrong, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the query?

Comment: If the user passes in @MustHavePicture=1, then I ONLY want to return Listings that have a picture.  If the user passes in @MustHavePicture=0, then I want to return ALL Listings regardless of whether they have pics or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Listing l
 WHERE IsDeleted = 1 
   AND ( @MustHasPicture <> 1 OR 
         (@MustHasPicture = 1 AND l.id IN (
              SELECT listingid
              FROM ListingPictures
            )
         )
       )
```

Comment: This results in the same listings being returned in both cases.

So, When @MustHavePicture=1, NON-pictured listings get returned.  It looked like the best candidate to me though...:(

Comment: that's what I get for not really testing things.  Edited to use another approach that I also haven't tested :-P

Comment: Ooops, my bad.  The Exists subquery needs to use a Where clause instead of an inner join.  Listing l ends up being ANOTHER alias, rather than using the alias from one level above.  So the subquery always returns true which is what was throwing off the results.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do a case - if the first part of an `and` fails, the second part will not be performed.

```
select
  *
from
  Listing l
Where
 l.IsDeleted = 1
 and ((@MustHasPicture = 1 and exists (...)) or 1)
```

Comment: This results in a syntax error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'."

Taking out the "OR 1" at the end makes it compile, but then it no returns NO listings in the event that the user passes in @MustHavePicture=0

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Listing l 
WHERE l.IsDeleted = 1 
AND (@MustHasPicture = 1 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ListingPictures] AS [lp]  
    WHERE lp.ListingID = l.ID) 
OR @MustHasPicture = 0)
```

But where does the Value @MustHasPicture come from?